No puedo acceder al archivo porque esta siendo usado en otro proceso, como puedo solucionar mi problema?
Estoy realizando un proyecto donde estoy utilizando SqlDependency, yo en mi codigo creo un log.txt para tener un historial de los cambios que se hacen en mi sql. Pero tengo el probelma de, No puedo acceder al archivo porque esta siendo usado en otro proceso. Como puedo solucionar esto.
  public void log_file(string logText)
  {
 

  // logText += DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + logText;
  ThreadSafe(() => richTextBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff") + "\t" + logText + Environment.NewLine));
  System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\log.txt", logText + Environment.NewLine);
  if (!System.IO.File.Exists("log.txt"))
      System.IO.File.Create("log.txt").Close();

  notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = logText;
  notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "ver";
  notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);

}


Hay mil librerias de log.. pero sacando eso, no entiendo tu codigo.. creas el archivo despues de agregarle cosas??? y cuando agregas, el archivo sigue prendido?? y al mismo tiempo que guardas en el log, mostras otras cosas en otros lados???

Si, se crea el archivo después de agregarle registros, es una app para monitorear cambios en mi BD, entonces cada que entra un dato o modificación la app me lo muestra en un DataGridView y tambien se guarda en el log.txt. Esta app la uso en tres maquinas diferentes y es por eso que me sale el mensaje del que estoy pidiendo ayuda.

Lo que quisiera hacer es cerrar el log.txt después de agregar los datos.

AppendText debería cerrar automáticamente el archivo, además de crearlo si este no existe, por lo que el if no es necesario´, quizás debas probar con AppendAllTextAsync

Me funciono el AppendAllTextAsync y tenias razón el if no debe de ir. @yussef

Que bien! otro cliente satisfecho :D
